# troubleshooting heatmaply: how to remove numbers from dendogram

Tags: r, heatmaply

I am integrating the heatmaply package into a shiny app that allows users the option to cluster either by row, column, both, or none. However when the either row or column is selected, the dendogram shows up with numbers as shown in the figure inside the red box.
[image] 
Does anybody know how to suppress these numbers from showing up?

Comment: Data and code used would be helpful

Comment: Are you using the CRAN or the GitHub version?

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/talgalili/heatmaply/issues/175) - it seems to be an oddity which arises only in some circumstances.